# why other element hide after checkbox checked in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recursion

I make a simple demo of `checkbox` .I also implemented `onchange handler` on my parent component.but I am facing a issue when I checked on `first parent` it hide other `parents`

here is my first state
[image]

After first parent `checked` it hide the other parents

[image]

https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-fire-cxp9c?file=/src/App.js

secondly I am not able to check `child checkbox`.Actually there is a problem in my `recursion` function

```
const setChecked = (data, label) => {
  // grab the first element
  console.log(data);

  const [current, ...rest] = data;

  return current && current.label === label
    ? [
        {
          ...current,
          checked: !current.checked,
          ...rest
        }
      ]
    : [current, ...setChecked(rest, label)];
};
```

here is my whole code

https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-fire-cxp9c?file=/src/App.js:642-970

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, hope the code below is self-explanatory.

```js
const setChecked = (data, label) => {
  return data.map((currData) => {
    const { childrens } = currData;
    const hasChildren = childrens && childrens.length > 0;

    if (currData.label === label) {
      return { ...currData, checked: !currData.checked };
    }

    if (hasChildren) {
      return { ...currData, childrens: setChecked(childrens, label) };
    }

    return currData;
  });
};
```

To avoid `Warning: A component is changing an uncontrolled input...`, use `i.checked === true` when passing the `checked` prop to your checkbox.

```js
...
<input
  type="checkbox"
  checked={i.checked === true} // here
  onChange={() => {
    handleChange(i);
    setTimeout(ab, 2000);
  }}
/>
```

[image: Edit confident-platform-q9hzy]